# Assegno su piazza / fuori piazza: where are both payable?

Tags: meaning

I have browsed through a great number of sources for the definition, and here are several of them from reliable dictionaries:

> **[Treccani:](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/piazza/)** *assegni su piazza, fuori piazza*, pagabili rispettivam. nella località stessa dove ha sede la banca che li ha
>   emessi o in località diversa.
>
> **[De Mauro:](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/piazza)** **fuori piazza** ... di assegno, pagabile in località differente dalla sede della banca che lo emette.
>
> [**Devoto-Oli:**](https://dizionario.devoto-oli.it/devotooli/dizionario#/masterDetail/words/) ***fuori piazza***, di assegno, pagabile in una
>   località diversa da quella in cui ha sede la banca che lo ha emesso,

and so on.

In the [term database of the Government of Canada](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&srchtxt=CHEQUE%20HORS%20PLACE), the definition is provided for the English equivalent, **out-of-town cheque**:

> A check [drawn] on a bank which is located outside the territory of
>   the clearing house with which the collecting bank is identified.

My question is whether an *assegno fuori piazza* is a cheque drawn by a bank on a bank located definitely in another town (I mean that a bank in Rome draws a cheque on a bank in Venice, and therefore this cheque **must be paid** in Venice) or it is a cheque without the city stated (which means that the cheque **can be paid anywhere** and it becomes *fuori piazza* if I present it before a bank in Venice and *su piazza* if I present it before a bank in Rome).

UPD. To put it briefly, *pagabile* = **can** be paid or *pagabile* = **must** be paid in this case?

Answer (score 1):

An “assegno fuori piazza” is a cheque that **can be** (but not necessarily) paid in a bank different from the one it was emitted (i.e. in a different location).

In general “pagabile” = can be paid (but not always), whereas “da pagare”, “deve essere pagata” or similar forms = must be payed.

As for references you cited Treccani which is one of the most reputable dictionaries of the Italian language.

In any case [here](https://www.gestioneassegni.com/differenze-tra-assegni-guida-completa/) is a website that describes how different cheques work:

> Assegno “fuori piazza”, in questo caso può essere riscosso in un comune del territorio nazionale diverso rispetto a quello del luogo di emissione e la banca deve pagarlo se la richiesta del beneficiario viene fatta entro 15 giorni

Trans.:

> “Fuori piazza” cheque, in this case the cheque **can be** (può essere) payed in a different municipality of the national territory from where it was emitted and the bank must pay it only if the request is done within 15 days.